# GeoReference image Raster to C# GMap

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have a tiff image and have the required information to Geo-reference it on the MAP. which called world file like [this](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=World_files_for_raster_datasets).

I used this e `GMAP.NET` , SO there are no more options to do GeoReferenceing??

From the ArcGIS link I can know the (X,Y) for each pixel from the image located at the MAP.
BUT how to do that ? is there any method to do to achieve my goal?

Another thing, that there java script API which is more comprehensive than GMAP API ??
is there any chance to use Javascript from C # ???